# Android 4.3 on Alcatel pop C7

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, 4.3-jelly-bean

I have an Alcatel OneTouch Pop c7 smartphone, wich apparently support only Android 4.2. I received an Alcatel Onetouch watch wich needs android 4.3 to work: how can I install this version of android on my phone?

Comment: I think your watch would be compatible with Android 4.4.1 which is available as a custom ROM (SlimKat 4.4.1) [here](http://www.gizmochina.com/2014/03/11/slimkat-4-4-1-kitkat-custom-rom-for-lenovo-gionee-huawei-alcatel-and-xiaomi/).

Comment: It looks like my phone it's not really supported for this ROM 
http://www.slimroms.net/index.php/supported-devices

Comment: It is very likely possible that the SlimKat I suggested isn't an officially supported ROM from Slimkat. It means somebody could have took the source code of SlimKat and unofficially ported it to your device, the reason why your device isn't listed on the site you linked. You may try it if the need is strong. Also, there is another port named MIUI (Kitkat) [here](http://www.htcmania.com/showthread.php?t=930576). Good Luck!